# VMTools Problem With 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 as a virtual machine using the install software provided by VMWare. This software reads the ISO file and creates the machine. This worked well with version 16.04 and it was working until I upgraded.  Ubuntu works welll but the cut and paste functionality to cut and paste between the guest and host no longer works.  This functionality should be enabled by the VMTools but with the 20.04 release the cut and paste no longer works.  VMTools are installed and are the latest per synaptics and also trying to install with apt. Has anyone run into this?  Could it be that the changes to 20.04 prevent the cut and paste from working?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022525; "Note: Whenever the Operating System (Linux Kernel) is updated, VMware Tools must be reinstalled."